# jQuery toggle divs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make two divs, and when one is clicked, it hides the other. Here's my code:

```
<head>

    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#top").click(function {
            $("#box").toggle();
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>

</body>
```

But when I click on `top`, nothing happens.

Edit: I changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top").click(function {
        $("#box").toggle();
    })
});
```

and it's still not working

Edit2: Turns out I was missing brackets in click(function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing brackets

```
$("#top").click(function() {
                        ^^
```

and since the jQuery is above the HTML it is binding to you will need to wrap the jQuery in a *document.ready* wrapper, for example:

```
$(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Alternatively, move the jQuery script tag below the HTML, for example:

```
<div id="top">one</div>
<div id="box">two</div>
<script>
    $("#top").click(function() {
        $("#box").toggle();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This fixed it (thought I guess I need the document.ready as well)

Comment: Yes, I was editing to include the _ready_ wrapper as well :-) Or you could move the jQuery `<script>` to below the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You missed the parenthesis after function. I think you need to put in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so that elements are ready before they are being access by `javasscript`.

```
$("#top").click(function (){
                         ^^
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux8L/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#top").click(function (){
        $("#box").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // do stuff when DOM is ready
 });
```

Read about [jquery-getting started here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

This is the write code which will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#top').click(function(){
     $("#box").toggle(500);
  });
});
```

You can check the example here http://jsfiddle.net/deepp2887/Pnamj/ . You can change the .toggle(500) animation speed as you want.